# How to make zsock_recv API non-blocking?

Tags: zeromq

Hello all I want to use the **`zsock_recv`** API in a non-blocking mode. Is there a way to do that? I can't find any reliable documentation on the `zsock` API's. Could anyone please point me towards one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ZeroMQ `zsock` API is documented here:

http://api.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:zsock

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am aware of this one. It would be really helpful if I can get some example code using these API's. I am sorry the question doesn't mention this.

Comment: The native ZeroMQ API has a self-explanatory **`ZMQ_NOBLOCK`** flag for `_recv()`-s. If `zsock` API does not reflect this native API option, one can use a poller-based strategy, with a zero-waiting == a non-blocking mode of returns from a poller-timeout controlled handler ( poller instance ) and your needs are easily being served by such a two-step way. http://api.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:zpoller